# How to send an email notification when a new document is added in a Document Library in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: document-library, alert, sharepoint-email

I'm pretty new to SharePoint 2013. I want to notify people by an email whenever any document is added to the document library. I tried to implement by clicking the `Edit in designer` link. But it redirects me to other place rather than opening the designer.

Please guide.

Comment: Please let me know what error text is show when you try opening it in designer.

Comment: Please do not post multiple questions in one post. Instead post each discrete question in a post of its own

Answer (score 6):

In order to send a notification email when a new document is uploaded, you can use the out of the box alerts provided by SharePoint. These alerts will send a notification mail to the individual on the event of new item creation in the document library.
Use [this](http://support.sherweb.com/Faqs/Show/how-to-create-an-alert-in-a-sharepoint-2013-site) link to create an alert.

Answer (score 4):

To add to William's comment...  When you create a workflow to email several people when a file is added, create a SharePoint Security group and send the email to the group.  So... when a new policy document is added... email the "Board of Directors".  This way when board members change you don't have to revisit this workflow.

Comment: Very true, good addition. I didn't even think of that...I think I need to go back and edit a few of my own workflows...

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the above answer provided by Mancy. In addition to that, if you wanted to add conditional emails to a list or library, you can design a workflow in SPD. If you go to the library and click the Library tab, you can click Workflow Settings, and then Create A Workflow In Sharepoint Designer. This SHOULD redirect you to SharePoint designer, assuming your previous problems don't crop up again.

Here's a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163181.aspx) to get you started on workflows, if you haven't made one yet. If your problems opening the library in SPD persist, please attach a screenshot so we can better understand your problem. Thanks!